# how @Ignore annotation will work in junit & mockito frameworks?

Tags: java, annotations, junit4

If @Ignore method will not make testCases to pass,whats the use of putting @Ignore on test method.We can directly delete the testMethod right?I am new to java & junit & mockito.Thanks in advance.

Comment: If it is a WIP you might want to temporarily ignore/disable the test instead of removing in and having to re-add it later. Or if it is flaky and you need to have it disabled for now until you have ample time to fix the flakiness. Those are just 2 reasons of wanting to disable it instead of removing it. Disabled/ignored tests also show up in a report and act as an indication things need to be done, removing them won't let them show up.`@Ignore` has nothing to do with Mockito just with JUnit4 (in JUnit5 is is `@Disabled` which is more descriptive imho).

Comment: Got clarity,Thank you!!!

Comment: And another doubt,is this Ignored test method will not considered for code coverage right?Thanks in advance

Comment: Ofcourse it won't be considered. Test coverage is measured with instrumentation and only code that is called during running tests gets flagged, if you ignore/disable tests those code paths aren't taken and thus not counted.